# How to use IPagedList paging feature with viewmodel and join in asp .net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to asp .net mvc and I am trying to implement IPagedList paging feature with viewmodel and join. Paging and searching is working fine for normal pages but I am not able to do with viewmodel and joins.

I am following this approach: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Here is my ViewModel Class:

```
 public class SponserDisplayViewModel
    {
        public Sponser Sponser { get; set; }
        public SponserDetail SponserDetail { get; set; }
        public SponserType SponserType { get; set; }
    } //--- Here All three are different classes.
```

Here What I have tried in Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchString, int? page, string btnSearch)
        {
            var viewModel = from s in db.Sponsers
                            join st in db.SponserTypes on s.SponserTypeId equals st.Id into st2
                            from st in st2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            select new SponserDisplayViewModel { Sponser = s, SponserType = st };

            if (btnSearch == "Reset")
            { searchString = string.Empty; }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                viewModel = from s in db.Sponsers
                            join st in db.SponserTypes on s.SponserTypeId equals st.Id into st2
                            from st in st2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            where st.Name.Contains(searchString)
                            select new SponserDisplayViewModel { Sponser = s, SponserType = st };
            }
            int pageSize = 20;
            int pageIndex = 1;
            pageIndex = page.HasValue ? Convert.ToInt32(page) : 1;


//==================Getting error here
            IPagedList<SponserDisplayViewModel> po = from s in db.Sponsers
                                            join st in db.SponserTypes on s.SponserTypeId equals st.Id into st2
                                            from st in st2.DefaultIfEmpty().OrderBy(a => a.DisplayOrder).ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize)
                                            select new SponserDisplayViewModel { Sponser = s, SponserType = st };

            return View(po);
        }
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my Answer:

```
var po = from s in db.Sponsers
         join st in db.SponserTypes on s.SponserTypeId equals st.Id into st2
         from st in st2.DefaultIfEmpty
         orderby st.DisplayOrder
         select new SponserDisplayViewModel { Sponser = s, SponserType = st };
return View(po.ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize));
```

Answer (score 0):

its working for me

```
int pagesize = 7, pageindex = 1;
        pageindex = page.HasValue ? Convert.ToInt32(page) : 1;
        var list = db.tbl_Category.Where(x => x.C_Status == 1).ToList();
        IPagedList<tbl_Category> showlis = list.ToPagedList(pageindex, pagesize);
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. When answering a question that already has an accepted answer, please be sure to add some additional insight into why the response you're providing is substantive and not simply echoing what's already been vetted by the original poster. 
This is especially important in "code-only" answers such as the one you've provided.